# Debugging with Chrome shows "Restore pages?" pop-up every time

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-2017

If I press the stop debugging button while debugging my ASP.NET Core app in Google Chrome it closes the Kestrel process window and the Chrome window that opens automatically on launching Debug. This is great and convenient!

Unfortunately it seems like Visual Studio closing Chrome in this way confuses Chrome and makes it think it has crashed. So every time I launch debugging in Visual Studio, a new Chrome window opens, and I see this annoying pop-up:

[image: "Restore pages?" pop-up]

I found a similar issue brought up [here, but it is for VS Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/issues/163#issuecomment-282365723) instead of VS2017. I don't think `launch.json` is a concept in VS2017 so I have no idea how to implement that workaround.

How can I prevent this from happening? Thanks!

Comment: I just accept that it's normal behavior of Visual Studio and Chrome. If you don't like it, I'd suggest contacting Microsoft and giving feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Close all open Chrome windows

Edit file:
"%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences"

Set:
"exit_type": "none"

and
"exited_cleanly":true

Change the Preferences file to readonly

Comment: I gave this a shot but it looks like as soon as I debugged and stopped debug again the setting got flipped back to "Crashed" and I saw the pop-up next launch.

Comment: i don't even have that file on my pc.

Comment: You need to set the Preferences file to readonly so that Chrome doesn't change it again