# Removing Chrome notification when developing with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

When you develop with ASP.NET and you start the debugger, the browser will start as well.
As you terminate the debugging session, the debugger gets killed.

And Chrome annoys the hell out of me at every restart:

[image]

Is there a way to remove permanently, until the end of times, this notification?

At the beginning of every debug session I have to close it.. again.. and again.

Comment: [Someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852838) asked this recently too.

Comment: Can you clarify if this Chrome is opening as new tab or new instance ?

Comment: @bandla: Chrome is opening in a new instance.

Answer (score -1):

Based on on the assumption that your Chrome is opening new instance instead of new tab (happened to me)

VS is trying to open new instance of Chrome with default settings (in newer version of VS i think )

> In VS, Go to Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General and turn off the
>   setting Enable JavaScript Debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE).

This will open chrome tab instead of new instance, which Google Chrome can understand if its closed by user or unexpected shut down. (this fixed for me)

See [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/)

Comment: This doesn't work: I want to keep the JS debugging; VS is doing the right thing by spawning a new instance; the issue is how to tell Chrome that we know what we're doing and we don't want a warning every time.

Comment: It is normal how chrome is reacting then. You can try submitting this in google forum for them to review may be.

Comment: Yes, it's a normal reaction; not providing an easy way to disable it is bad and I was hoping someone here knew a hack